# Convert code to AJAX jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, google-chrome-extension

I have created a Chrome Extension which converts the data from the `data-href` attribute and applies it to the `href` attribute from a Google Search. Here is the current code:

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    var e = $("#search");
    var d = e.find("a[data-href]");
    $(d).attr("href", function() {
        return $(this).attr("data-href");
    });
});
```

This code is a bit slow because it is running every time there is some kind of change to the DOM, however I was wondering is it possible to convert this code using AJAX and will run when there is an AJAX request from Google?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried using `$("#search").on('DOMSubtreeModified', fn)` to cut down the number of elements affected?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorporating @RoryMcCrossan's comment into this answer, the first thing to try is to reduce the scope of your search.

```
$("#search").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    $(this).find("a[data-href]").each(function() {
        this.href = this.getAttribute("data-href");
    });
});
```

Note also the use of [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) to perform the relatively simple task of transferring one attribute to another - simpler code runs faster!

As for your question of hooking into AJAX requests, depending on how they are done it may be possible. For instance, on my own project there's a global function called `ajax(url,data)` that returns a jQuery XHR object. Knowing this, you can do something like:

```
var original_ajax = window.ajax;
window.ajax = function(url,data) {
    // do pre-processing here, if needed
    var ret = original_ajax(url,data);
    // do something to ret, for instance attach listeners
    // we know it's a jQuery XHR object, so `.success` might be a good start
    return ret;
};
```

Of course, exact implementation details may vary - my project actually returns a wrapped XHR which takes some extra hacking to hook into but it's still possible. You will need to research how the target website makes its AJAX requests and hook accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your sample code :) I will also simplify the code and will do some research on how Google makes its AJAX requests.

Comment: Hi, I found that Google is using this url for AJAX requests (search while typing) https://www.google.com.au/s?sclient=psy. How would I implement your code with that URL? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

MutationEvents are bad at performance and thus are [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events). Use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead.

```
function initMO(root) {
    var MO = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
    var observer = new MO(function(mutations) {
        observer.disconnect();
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
             walk(mutation.target);
        });
        observe();
    });
    var opts = { childList: true, subtree: true };
    var observe = function() {
        observer.takeRecords();
        observer.observe(root, opts);
    };
    observe();
}

function walk(root) {
    $(root).find("a[data-href]").each(function() {
        this.href = this.getAttribute("data-href");
    });
});

var target = document.getElementById("search");
walk(target);
initMO(target);
```